# vba arrays from google apps script

Tags: vba, excel, google-apps-script

In google docs I saw someone have a script that wrote a function that was like:

```
function createChargeList () {
    return [['No.', 'Name', 'Cooldown', 'Power', 'Energy Loss', 'Type', 'Damage Window Start'], 
          [1.0, 'AerialAce', 240.0, 55.0, 33.0, 3.0, 190.0], [2.0, 'AirCutter', 270.0, 60.0, 50.0, 3.0, 180.0], [3.0, 'AncientPower', 350.0, 70.0, 33.0, 6.0, 285.0], [4.0, 'AquaJet', 260.0, 45.0, 33.0, 11.0, 170.0], [5.0, 'AquaTail', 190.0, 50.0, 33.0, 11.0, 120.0]
}
```

I am trying to teach myself coding in VBA and I'm having trouble understanding how something like the above code would translate into a vba script for Excel.

Comment: This looks like lines from a text/flat file and probably would be better organized in a different structure than an array for VBA purposes.

Comment: @DavidZemens would you suggest maybe creating a table with all these elements in it and then calling the table itself as a variable? I'm not sure if that would work but I thought of that as a possible solution. There are 12 columns and approximately 251 total rows (headers and data) with more rows that I might add later. The example I provided was a very small sample of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps script is based on javascript. VBA is based on Visual Basic. Hardcoding it is a possibility but you end up with some  funky array and you're then limited to VBA's clunky array methods (or lack thereof).

```
Function createChargeList()
    Dim var(5)
    var(0) = [{"No.", "Name", "Cooldown", "Power", "Energy Loss", "Type", "Damage Window Start"}]
    var(1) = [{1.0, "AerialAce", 240.0, 55.0, 33.0, 3.0, 190.0}]
    var(2) = [{2.0, "AirCutter", 270.0, 60.0, 50.0, 3.0, 180.0}]
    var(3) = [{3.0, "AncientPower", 350.0, 70.0, 33.0, 6.0, 285.0}]
    var(4) = [{4.0, "AquaJet", 260.0, 45.0, 33.0, 11.0, 170.0}]
    var(5) = [{5.0, "AquaTail", 190.0, 50.0, 33.0, 11.0, 120.0}]
    createChargeList = var
    
End Function
```

Or you could "hardcode" it to a `Dictionary` or `Collection` or an `ArrayList` (of `ArrayList`s). There would be some benefits to using a Dict or ArrayList because they have other methods you can use. Dictionary example, this is not how I would structure it but it shows how you could do it:

```
Function createChargeDict()
    Dim d As Object
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d("No.") = Array(1#, 2#, 3#, 4#, 5#)
    d("Name") = Split("AerialAce,AirCutter,AncientPower,AquaJet,AquaTail", ",")
    'etc...
    Set createChargeDict = d
End Function
```

But, it's going to be difficult to "hardcode" it if it's more than a very small amount of data e.g., per Tim's answer (or likewise through what I did, above), and of course if anything *changes* you need to go and edit the code.

Another option would be to save the data as a CSV or otherwise delimited file and read it in to an array/dict/list/collection at runtime.

## What I would do (Opinion)

Another more common approach -- as you inquired about in your comments -- would be to simply create a table on a worksheet (optionally: hide the worksheet so user's can't mess it up), assign a `Name` to represent the table's range, and then you can just refer to the range's `.Value` property which will return an array.

The added benefits of this is that you can use all of the `Worksheet` methods and functions against the range of cells (or as a Table/`ListObject` on a sheet), and then you can do a lot more with it in terms of filtering, slicing, finding elements, matching/indexing, etc., and it's also easier to update.

Answer (score 2):

VBA doesn't have the same type of array literal construct you find in javascript

This is what you have if you want a single-line assignment:

```
Dim a

a = Array("a", "b", "c") '>>0-based 1-d array

a = ["a", "b"] '>> *1*-based 1-d array

a = [{"a", "b";"c","d"}] '>> *1*-based 2-d array
```

Note that last one is not the same as your example (ie. not an array of arrays)